# Algolia Search - changing order of instant search results

Tags: search, advanced-search

I'm getting started with Algolia Search using [this plugin](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento). When I start typing in the search box, it starts showing results in a dropdown menu.

And I can't figure out how to change the sort order of those results.

The default is categories, products, pages, and then attributes. And I want the order to be products, attributes, categories, pages.

Am I looking at something in the settings wrong? Or do I need to start editing the underlying code?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify that in the template => https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/master/design/frontend/template/topsearch.phtml#L1044-L1247

The order of display is the order the objects are added in the hogan_objs variable.

It should get easier in the coming weeks see => https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/issues/182

Comment: A ha, I may give this a go to see what I can do with it. But it looks like it's going to be pretty easy to break, so it's probably better to 'reset the client expectations' and tell them this is a feature that's still forthcoming.